# Cleaning up a basic Python script that takes and recites a pizza order

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to learning Python. I wrote a very basic script that takes your pizza order and recites it back when you're done placing your order:

```
available_toppings = ['mushrooms', 'onions', 'green peppers', 'pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'extra cheese','sausage','spinach']
requested_toppings = []
size = input("Would you like a large, medium, or small pizza? ")

ordering = True
while ordering == True:
    topping = input("What topping would you like on your pizza? ")
    if topping.lower() in available_toppings:
        print("Yes, we have that.")
        requested_toppings.append(topping)

    elif topping not in available_toppings:
        print("Sorry, we do not have " + topping + ".")

    add_more = False
    while add_more == False:
        answer = input("Would you like to add another topping? Yes or no? ")
        if answer.lower() == "y" or answer.lower() == "yes":
            add_more = True

        elif answer.lower() == "n" or answer.lower() == "no":
            print("Ok, you ordered a {} ".format(size) + "pizza with:")
            for requested_topping in requested_toppings:
                print(requested_topping)
                add_more = True
                ordering = False

        elif answer.lower() != "n" or answer.lower() != "no" or answer.lower() != "y" or answer.lower() != "yes":
            print("Sorry, I didn't catch that.")
            continue
```

I was just wondering if anyone has any tips to clean up the code a bit. I'm sure there is an easier way to accomplish what this script can do and would love to learn some tricks. I would also like to add that while loops still confuse me a bit and even though I got this to run, I really don't know if I did them right.

Comment: You don't need `elif topping not in available_toppings:`. It's fine with just `else:`

Comment: `print("Ok, you ordered a {} ".format(size) + "pizza with:")` can be `print(f"Ok, you ordered a {size} pizza with:")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should add `else` instead of elif in -

```
elif topping not in available_toppings:
    print("Sorry, we do not have " + topping + ".")
```

You can use

```
else:
   print("Sorry, we do not have " + topping + ".")
```

And instead of

```
elif answer.lower() != "n" or answer.lower() != "no" or answer.lower() != "y" or answer.lower() != "yes":
            print("Sorry, I didn't catch that.")
            continue
```

You should use

```
else:
    print("Sorry, I didn't catch that.")
    continue
```

And you should also check if the size of the pizza is correct, it can be invalid. You should also print the topping list, as it will help user pick.

Comment: You can even add a few functions if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif answer.lower() == "n" or answer.lower() == "no":
       print("Ok, you ordered a {} ".format(size) + "pizza with:")
       for requested_topping in requested_toppings:
            print(requested_topping)
       add_more = True
       ordering = False
```

keep them out of the for loop and rest other things avi mentioned

and  print the list of topping

can you clear your problem related to not understanding while loop